# Calling a function in window.onload does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

### Background

I have a simple application with a search textbox and a repeater.
When user enters a text in the search textbox, the list is filtered by the entered text. Here's the javascript code which is working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            localStorage.setItem("filterString", this.value);
            filter(this);
        });
    });

    function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val().toLowerCase();

        $(".panel").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

### What I am trying to do

I want to the application to keep the filtered list when user comes back to this page.

The approach I'm trying to make is to store the search string by using the localStorage:
`localStorage.setItem("filterString", this.value);"`

And then when the window.onload gets called, I retrieve the filterString, render the search textbox, and call the filter function.

### Issues and what I've tried

Here's the code I've tried:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
    {
         var filterString = localStorage.getItem("filterString");
         txtSearch.value = filterString;
         filter(filterString);
    }
 }
```

The filter still works fine on `keyup` but does not work on `onload`.

I've also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("filterString", this.value);
        filter(this);
    });
    //Added this
    filter(localStorage.getItem("filterString"));
});
```

This is still not working and filter on `keyup` stops working if I do this.

Why can't I call the `filter` function?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I guess - you are storing this.value whereas you'll need element in filter function .. Try to change the function to accept input's value as a parameter and pass the value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call the `filter` function by passing the string as a parameter, and it expects you to pass the `element`.

So, you should change your last code to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').keyup(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("filterString", this.value);
    filter(this);
  });
  // Change the input value to the localStorage value
  $('input').val(localStorage.getItem("filterString"));
  // And then, send the element to the filter
  filter($('input')[0]); ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add following in document.ready function . Remember to call it after your existing function.

```
 $('input').keyup();
```

like this

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        localStorage.setItem("filterString", this.value);
        filter(this);
    });
   $('input').keyup(); //added here ,after your keyup function
});
```